# How to retrieve events list form iCal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How to retrieve events list from iCal application through coding? Is it possible to get the events list?

Answer (score -1):

The Event Kit framework provides classes for accessing and modifying calendar event information.

Check out Apple's documentation on this: [Event Kit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/EventKitFrameworkRef.pdf)

Also look into [EKEventStore](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567) class which represents the Calendar database. It is an application’s point of contact for accessing calendar data.

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.